# I am trying to get data from row to match into defined columns

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP / MySQL

I have two tables one is `customers` the other is `cust_data`

there is a field that matches the two it is `ListID`

Now inside the `cust_data` table the data is listed as `cust_data`

columns:

```
ListID  DataName  DataValue
 1      type      something
 1      Region    something
```

customers
columns:

```
ListID Name Address City State Zip Phone
```

I want to get the results as

```
Name Address City State Zip Phone Type Region
```

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: I am familiar with the join command I would join on the ListID column but I do not know how to make sure the type goes under type and that region would go under region because the data is in rows and not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT customers.*, data_type.DataValue AS Type, data_region.DataValue AS Region
FROM   customers
  JOIN cust_data AS data_type ON (
         data_type.ListID   = customers.List_ID
     AND data_type.DataName = 'Type'
  )
  JOIN cust_data AS data_region ON (
         data_region.ListID   = customers.List_ID
     AND data_region.DataName = 'Region'
  )
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN qb_dataext AS data_type ON ( qb_customer.ListID =qb_dataext.Entity' at line 4

Comment: @Steven: `JOIN qb_dataext` isn't in my answer above.. please post somewhere the full query you are using.

Comment: I fixed that there was a , when there shouldn't have been now i have a new problem

Comment: $res = mysql_query("SELECT  `CompanyName` As Customer, `BillAddress_Addr2` As Street1, `BillAddress_State` As State, `BillAddress_PostalCode` As Zip, `AccountNumber` As 'Account No.', `CustomerType_FullName` As 'Customer Type', `SalesRep_FullName` As Rep, data_type.DataExtValue AS Type, data_region.DataExtValue AS Region


FROM $table1 JOIN $table2 AS data_type ON (
        $table1.ListID = $table2.Entity_ListID 
     AND data_type.DataExtName = 'Type'
  )
  JOIN $table2 AS data_region ON (
         $table1.ListID = $table2.Entity_ListID 
     AND data_region.DataExtName = 'Region'
  )

")

;

Comment: Unknown column 'qb_dataext.Entity_ListID' in 'on clause'

Comment: But that column does exist The actual tables are qb_customers and qb_dataext I just shortend them in the original problem

Comment: @Steven: You're assigning `$table2` the aliases `data_type` and `data_region` - you have to use those aliases when referring to the table (in the `ON` clause and elsewhere).

Comment: that fixed it now it will do the first join but I am running out of memory when both of the join statements are in

Comment: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1572864) (tried to allocate 1048560 bytes)

Comment: One more issue with this. if there is not a value then the row doesn't exist. This is only including records that match both of the join statements. It is not showing everything else that meet only one of the join statements..

Comment: Think I got it using Left Join

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a group query.  The fact that you can group by ListID to get a single row makes this relatively straightforward-- just select conditionally and alias the *DataValue* field as needed:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Address, c.City, c.State, c.Zip, c.Phone,
    MAX (CASE WHEN d.DataName = 'type' THEN DataValue ELSE NULL END) AS  `Type`,
    MAX (CASE WHEN d.DataName = 'Region' THEN DataValue ELSE NULL END) AS  `Region`
FROM customers c, cust_data d
WHERE c.ListID = d.ListID
GROUP BY c.ListID, c.Name, c.Address, c.City, c.State, c.Zip, c.Phone
```

Comment: `[]` identifier quotes aren't valid in MySQL.  Use backtick instead.

Comment: when using group by it will only get the result for type it will not get the result for region.

Comment: @Steven I'm not sure why that would be.  You mean it's showing null?  Please try my updated answer also, the problem could have been that I didn't group by all the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: This still does not work it will return only the first result I am assuming because when it groups them it ignores the multiple rows that contain the ListID and only takes the first one. I will try grouping by the ListID on cust_data

Comment: @Steven that's the point of using **MAX** -- it should select the appropriate *DataValue* and ignore the Null values.  Apparently I'm missing something, though... not sure what.

Comment: not sure it will get what ever value is listed first but not the other.